# Bearer Token in Guzzle HTTP 6.1 not working

Tags: php, phpunit, authorization, bearer-token, guzzle6

I have a problem with my Bearer-Authorization in Guzzle-HTTP.
I use it to test my PHP-REST-API with PHPUnit.

here is my test method:

```
 public function testGetMe()
{
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => $this->apiBaseURL
    ]);        
    $data = ['email' => $email, 'password' => '12345'];
    $client->post('register', [
            'form_params' => $data]
    );
    $responseJson = json_decode($response->getBody());
    $myToken = $responseJson->data->token;

    $response = $client->request('GET', 'users', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization'      => 'Bearer '.$myToken
        ],
        'debug' => true
    ]);
}
```

But if I set the token hard coded like this:

```
 public function testGetMe()
{
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => $this->apiBaseURL
    ]);        
    $data = ['email' => $email, 'password' => '12345'];
    $client->post('register', [
            'form_params' => $data]
    );
    $responseJson = json_decode($response->getBody());
    $myToken = eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0NjQ5NzExMzQsImp0aSI6IjByR3FpOW15Rm1rRGo2TU9sMVhkK3dRU3p1V0pWejM1UEhiU2dTMmg5SEU9IiwiaXNzIjoiQXBwTmFtZSIsIm5iZiI6MTQ2NDk3MTE0NCwiZXhwIjoxNDY0OTczMTQ0LCJzdWIiOiJ0ZXN0QG1haWwuZGUifQ.yA4a_S6ILCeqENm00H712g9uF5g9eSz_BmnaMDdZ2r4p5e1q88g0T09IG2WKCi1oExoBfQ8VTmKeX6ZQv0RydQ;

    $response = $client->request('GET', 'users', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization'      => 'Bearer '.$myToken
        ],
        'debug' => true
    ]);
}
```

and also with Postman, it is working.
It's the same token which I receive from my REST-API.

Do you have any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Did you double check that the token response is *exactly the same* as hardcoded string?

Comment: Hey Tomasz, yesss. I checked it 1000 times... -.- & also when I copy the token into postman and then send the request everything is working fine.

Comment: UPDATE... Also when I debug the code & wait on line: $response = $client->request('GET', 'users'... the test is ok... seems to be something wrong with asynch requesting -.-

Comment: Sorry, the problem was on my api on the generation of my JWT. Sorry Sorry Sorry!